# How create QActions and their signals according to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, qmenu, qaction

I am using python3 and PyQt4. I want to create a menu with actions, the number of which differs according to an array. I want each of them to save the corresponding information, saved in the array, to a variable. Creating variable number of events seems impossible. So how can i create an event which does different work, according to the action it was activated by?
That' s my code:

```
def buildLoadSettings(self):
    self.settings = array
    for i in range(len(self.settings)):
        exec("self.settings" + str(i) + " = QtGui.QAction('" + self.settings[i][0] + "', self)")
        exec("self.loadMenu.addAction(self.settings" + str(i) + ")")
```

I want to connect each of the actions with an event and finally save the "self.settings[i][1]" to a variable "settings".
Sorry for my novice question.

Comment: explain your question, please

Comment: I just wanted to create multiple actions, with variable number and an event which knows, which action it was called by, so that it uses the corresponding data. ekhumoro gave the exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you're trying to achieve, but there are several APIs that should help. There is certainly no need to use ugly `exec` calls like you are at present.

Here are a few ideas:

1. Use `QAction.setData()` to associate some data with each action:

   ```
       for item in self.settings:
           action = QtWidgets.QAction(item[0], self)
           action.setData(item[1])
           self.loadMenu.addAction(action)
   ```
2. Use `QMenu.actions()` to access the actions, rather than creating attributes:

   ```
       action = self.loadMenu.actions()[2]
       print((action.text(), action.data()))
   ```
3. Connect a slot to `QMenu.triggered()` to handle all of its actions in one place:

   ```
       self.loadMenu.triggered.connect(self.handleLoadMenu)

   def handleLoadMenu(self, action):
       # "action" is the action that was clicked
       text = action.text()
       data = action.data()
       print('Action Clicked: ("%s", %s)' % (text, data))
   ```

PS:

If you want to get/set attributes dynamically, use `getattr` and `setattr`:

```
    # self.settings2 = action
    setattr(self, "settings%s" % 2, action)
    # action = self.settings2
    action = getattr(self, "settings%s" % 2)
```